# ASP.NET fails to detect IE10 causing _doPostBack is undefined JavaScript error

Tags: javascript, asp.net, internet-explorer-10, dopostback

ASP.NET fails to detect IE10 causing the following error:

> `_doPostBack` is undefined JavaScript error

or maintain FF5 scrollbar position.

There is a bug in the browser definition files that shipped with .NET 2.0 and .NET 4, namely that they contain definitions for a certain range of browser versions. But the versions for some browsers (like IE 10) aren't within those ranges any more. Therefore, ASP.NET sees them as unknown browsers and defaults to a down-level definition, which has certain inconveniences, like that it does not support features like JavaScript.

The fix available at http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2600100 for Win7 SP1, is not working for me. Please help me on this. 
My working environment is:

.NET Framework 3.5 SP1, Windows Server 2003

Comment: The summary of the hotfix mentions it supports Windows Server 2003 and Microsoft .NET Framework 3.5 Service Pack 1 (SP1) which is your environment, right?

Answer (score 1):

Try installing the Browser Definition Files from NuGet http://nuget.org/packages/App_BrowsersUpdate into your project. Browser Definition files for ASP.NET 4 are compatible with ASP.NET 3.5, so you should be okay. You may have had an issue installing the hotfix you mentioned if you do not have the appropriate permissions on your machine.

Answer (score 1):

if you continue to have this issue, there is a small code snippet you can add to your global.asax that will resolve the problem as a temporary workaround until you have your server(s) patched.

http://ronniediaz.com/2013/02/07/ie10-imagebutton-_dopostback-undefined-bug-with-update-panel-script-manager/

Comment: Consider adding the small code snippet instead of linking off to another site. If that link ever breaks, your answer will be of no value.

Answer (score 1):

The KB 2600100 hotfix were replaced by Microsoft .NET Framework 4 Reliability Update 2 (KB2600217)  http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2600217 - the documentation states that this update resolves 7 issues including two that you mentioned. But it seems that you need to use Microsoft .NET framework 4 instead of 3.5. If the  KB 2600100 hotfix is not working, you might want to check IIS Server Manager to find out what .NET framework version is being used for running your web site.

Answer (score 0):

First temp fix I applied to our websites is adding  to the master pages.
But I don't want to force this mode for the rest of the sites lifetime, I want a decent solution. I removed the fix in the master page, installed hotfix from KB2600100, but problems didn't disappear.
Applied the script from Ronnie's link, that did the trick.

Still, I'm wondering why the hotfix didn't help.